# Setup required to communicate with QuickBooks

Tags: qbxml

Sorry if this is a dumb question but I have spent hours looking for a solution.

I want to connect to a QuickBooks Company file that is installed on a server from a workstation that is on the network.

I am running the AddCust.exe that is supplied with the QuickBooks SDK.

1. What do I need to install on the server to make this work.
2. I am running the executable on the workstation. Do I have to have QuickBooks installed on the workstation that I want to run this app? I have installed the ABXMLRP2Installer on the workstation.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but in case anyone is still searching....

This answer is based on Quickbooks SDK 11.0.
You need to install the SDK on the machine running Quickbooks.
Next, you will need two programs that are part of the SDK:

- RDS6ServerInstaller.exe    RDS6ClientInstaller.exe

You will find these somewhere in the SDK install location:
on my machine, they were in:
C:\Program Files\Intuit\IDN\QBSDK11.0\tools\Installers

Here is a good write up on how to get this going...
[http://www.h2officesolutions.com/h2os_custguide/Customizing_the_RDS_server.htm](https://web.archive.org/web/20150504222359/http://www.h2officesolutions.com:80/h2os_custguide/Customizing_the_RDS_server.htm)

Use the sample program provided in the SDK called SDKTestPlus3 for testing.

Be prepared for some serious tinkering and time to get this going....

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install anything on the server if you install QuickBooks and the required SDK components on the workstation. It is also possible to use Remote Data Sharing (RDS) to access data on the server, but it is much simpler to install QuickBooks on the workstation as long as you don't mind using a license for that purpose.

SDK applications always require that SDK components be installed; SDK components do *not* come pre-installed with QuickBooks. In the case of the AddCust sample app, the QBXMLRP2 installer is what you need.